# error in if else in bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
i=0
EDA="xx7p2"
while read line
do
    echo "i is --- $i"
    echo " PACKAGE IS - --$EDA--"
    #echo $line "\n"
    if (( $i > 0 ))
    then
        package=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        echo "EDA PACKAGE IN LOOP IS ---$Eda_package---"
        if [ "$package" == "$EDA" ] ; then
            #then
            well_bias=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
            biasmap=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
            unified=$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}')
            echo "eda pack --$package bias is --$wel biasmap is --$biasmap  unified-           --$unified"
        fi
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done < config.list
```

Here the statements inside the second if statement is not executed even if the two variables are same. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Any particular reason why the second `then` is commented out?  Edit - sorry, I mis-read the code (indentation would help though).

Comment: i have used then in the if line itself. was trying different syntax.

Comment: How do you know they are the same, you don't print `$package` anywhere?

Comment: yes i have printed it and seen that everything is same.

Comment: Note that you are printing `$Eda_package` within the loop

Comment: Please use indentation to emphasize the structure of your code. If you're certain that your problem is well described with 2 simple, nested if statements, reduce your code and make a [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) without those noisy, unrelevant EDA, awk, PACKAGE things. $1, 2, 3, 4 should be enough. Now it is too localized. While generalizing it, you will probably solve it already yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a simplified version of your problem to get it nailed down.
I can't reproduce your problem with this sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=$1
a=$2
while read line
do
    if (( $i > 0 ))
    then
        echo "1st if "+$i
        if [ "$a" == "foo" ] ; then
            echo "2nd if"
        fi
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done < nfoo.sh
```

called nfoo.sh and calling it `./nfoo.sh 4 bar, ./nfoo.sh -4 bar, ./nfoo.sh 4 foo and ./nfoo.sh -4 foo`.

Might your error be in the package-assignement? You don't need awk for such a simple task. For a single word, to just extract the first word, you would use `echo ${line/ */}` while I see nothing wrong in your awk-statement.

Since you extract more arguments, I would suggest an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=$1
a=$2
while read line
do
    if (( $i > 0 ))
    then
        arr=($line)
        echo "1st if "+$i
        if [ "if" == "${arr[0]}" ] ; then
            echo "2nd if: " $line
        fi
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done < nfoo.sh
```

Btw.: Where is the else, the headline is talking about?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: based on more testing with the small script below:

Having the `$` as part of the string in `package` variable was a problem for me. If I escape it with a `\$` I get it to work with the correct comparison operator mentioned below.

Use this for comparison (note the *space* before/after the `=`)

```
 if [ "$package" = "$EDA" ] ; then
```

Without the space the expression seems to evaluate always to true. (Also, as an aside, using `==` without spaces before/after will result in an `[: 11: $EDAx: unexpected operator`)

I used this small script for testing, you can use to verify your own constructs, hope it's helpful. This works correctly as shown

```
#!/bin/bash

package="\$EDA"
echo $package

if [ "$package" = "\$EDA" ] ; then
    echo "The same"
else
    echo "Not the same"
fi
```

*Note1*: I added the `else` to be certain of the outcome of the comparison, as your script doesn't contain any `else`

*Note2*: It's always better to explicitly specify what shell to run rather than to depend on some external implicit environment settings, so I would recommend you add the `#!/bin/bash` to your script, it certainly won't hurt.

[Other Comparison Operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)  from the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) shows:

> **string comparison**
>
> =
>
> is equal to
>
> if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
>
> **Note the whitespace framing the** =.
>
> if [ "$a"="$b" ] is not equivalent to the above.
>
> == is equal to
>
> if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
>
> This is a synonym for =.

Comment: just want to know how bash interprets the above statement.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't understand as this solves the OP's problem (accepted answer). Downvote w/o explanation helps *no one* (OP, SO or me ..)

Comment: after correction the loop is entering for all other comparisons as well which is not supposed to happen since they are false.

Comment: the string comparison is now not working..for every condition the loop is getting executed.

Comment: no it has not solved my problem. previously the comparison was not working for the right one but now it is working even for wrong data.

Comment: I dont have though but i execute my script in bash shell only.

Comment: is there any difference between = and == in bash when u use string comparisons

Comment: @cdarke spaces *are* require for the single `=` to work correctly. It will cause an error with the `==`.

Comment: no it has not yet solved my problem. even after using = the loop is not getting executed even for the right match

Comment: @monucool Escaping the $ and using the = with a space before and after makes the if/else-statement work correctly which you asked about in your question (please try it with the small script I posted yourself). You may have another problem in your original script, but I believe the if/else is solved.

Comment: Spaces are required for both = and ==, with both the old Bourne shell syntax of single [ ] (which you are using) and the 'newer' Korn shell syntax of [[ ]].  == is preferred bacuse most programming languages use them, and = is not valid in arithmetic comparisons (( )).  However, = or == should make no difference to  this problem.

Comment: @cdarke I appreciate the additional information, but that still leaves me wondering why with `/bin/bash` I get the error `[: 11: $EDAx: unexpected operator` when using this: `if [ "$package" == "\$EDA" ] ; then` (note the spaces before/after). Seems very finicky and makes me happy that I do most of my programming in Python rather than the shell.

Comment: It could be that it is executing the Bourne shell if you don't use a #! line - ever tried a Python script without the #! line? = is in the POSIX standard, but == is not (I just checked), so I suppose it is not surprising they have different behaviour.  However, the bash man pages say they are equivalent.

Comment: @monucool: It's very confusing that `$EDA` is both a variable and a literal value (with a literal dollar sign). You should change that.